# OAuth for Enterprise account

Tags: box-api

I'm creating a web app for my company that will keep a number of files in sync with the files on Box. This will be done by using a cron job running every hour.

I have the application working by setting the developer token in my account, this was done for testing whilst I was building the application.

Now this is working I want to get the authentication working so I can just leaving this running. So I'm trying to work out if there is a way I can have an API key for our enterprise account or if I will have to implement OAuth and connect one user to the application, which seems to be a bit overkill?

Comment: Who would those documents belong to when you move them into Box?  A single user, or is this 'script' meant to run on a shared drive moving content for various different users?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use one of the SDKs, which take care of refreshing the tokens for you.

Essentially what you'll need is a keystore to store the tokens.  You could store the Refresh-token only.  When your cron wakes up, use the refresh token to get a new access-token and refresh-token.  Store the new refresh token in your keystore.  Then make your API calls using the Access-token, and then go back to sleep.